# Different Similarities for one field in solr

Tags: solr, similarity

I implemented a Similarity which is based on the DefaultSimilarity changing the calculation for the idf.
To work with this CustomSimilarity and the DefaultSimilarity from our application I have one field with the default and a copyfield with my similarity.

Concerning the extra space needed for this field I wonder if there is a way to have my similarity or the default for the SAME field. Because there are no differences for the index. 
E.g. by creating a SearchComponent to have something like solr/mySelect for queries with my similarity and the usual solr/select for the default similarity?
How could I achieve this, has anybody a hint or another idea?

Cheers,
 Sascha

Comment: The doco says "At indexing time, the indexer calls computeNorm(FieldInvertState), ". I assume you have not changed computeNorm, and you do not have different analysis chains. Could you show the changed calculation?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It was an error in solr/lucene which is fixed now:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-7395
But I forgot to change this entry here